# Robot Framework: How to build teardown dynamically

Tags: robotframework

I am trying to build teardown actions dynamically in my test case. For e.g. for every step in the test case I am having a corresponding teardown step. So depending on at which point the test case fails, I am trying to run only those many clean actions in the teardown.

I am expecting something like below to work (unfortunately `Run Keywords` need to have `AND` mentioned specifically in the syntax)

```
*** Settings ***
Library    Collections

*** Test Cases ***
Sample Test1
    ${Cleanup KWS}=    Create List    Log    Cleanup Step1
    Log    Test Step1
    ${Cleanup KW}=    Create List    Log    Cleanup Step2    AND
    ${Cleanup KWS}=    Combine Lists    ${Cleanup KW}    ${Cleanup KWS}
    Log    Test Step2
    ${Cleanup KW}=    Create List    Log    Cleanup Step3    AND
    ${Cleanup KWS}=    Combine Lists    ${Cleanup KW}    ${Cleanup KWS}
    Log    Test Step3

    [Teardown]    Run Keywords    @{Cleanup KWS}
```

If the above is possible, the test case execution might be more efficient (if test fails in-between) and/or I can avoid unnecessary failures in the teardown stage.

Is there any other elegant way to support the above kind of desired behavior?

Comment: Have you tried parsing ${Cleanup KWS} with a for loop and using "Run Keyword"?

Comment: Thanks @Pekka. I guess I will need to use "Run Keyword And Return Status" to avoid potential premature exit? Also I should be ANDing the statuses to return a final upper level keyword status? This will indicate teardown failure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by defining each teardown step in the `Keywords` sections:

```
*** Keywords ***
Teardown_Step_1
    log to console    Teardown for step 1

Teardown_Step_2
    log to console    Teardown for step 2

Teardown_Step_3
    log to console    Teardown for step 3

Execute teardown steps
    [Documentation]    Execute a list of keywords
    [Arguments]  @{keywords}
    [Return]     @{result}

    @{result}=   create list
    FOR  ${keyword}  IN  @{keywords}
        ${keyword result}=  Run keyword  ${keyword}
        Append to list  ${result}  ${keyword result}
    END
```

And then in the test you can use the above keywords like this:

```
Sample Test1

    @{teardown_list} =   create list

    Log    Test Step1
    append to list    ${teardown_list}     Teardown_Step_1
    Log    Test Step2
    append to list    ${teardown_list}     Teardown_Step_2
    Log    Test Step3
    append to list    ${teardown_list}     Teardown_Step_3

    [Teardown]    Execute teardown steps    @{teardown_list}
```

Comment: Thanks @Dan Constantinescu. I believe, in the for loop, I should use "Run Keyword And Return Status" instead of "Run Keyword" for potential premature exit. Also I should AND all statuses to return final status. However, this will lose the return values from the keywords (but not every keyword will return values).